Why curl shows different outcome with --verbose and without it?
I have Azure AKS Cluster runing at 1.28.9 Kubernetes. It is running in Subscription X, Region XX. I have also Firewall Premium setup in Subscription Y + proper NSGs, Region YY. Both vnets peer each other.
In cluster I have Ingress resource + Nginx Ingress Contoller. I do not have Egress (Network Policies).
In cluster run pods with wget and curl inside. If I do "curl www.google.com" I can see that access is denied into Internet, BUT if I do " curl -v www.google.com" I can see HTTPS 200 - connection established".
My question is: why is like this?
I have made some research online and came to conclusions:

DNS issues can sometimes cause non-verbose curl requests to fail if the DNS resolution process encounters issues. Verbose mode might provide more information about the DNS resolution process and handle failures differently.
Verbose mode might alter the timing or structure of the packets sent, potentially allowing them to pass through NSGs or firewall rules that would otherwise block them.
Verbose mode in curl might introduce slight delays or retries that are not present in standard mode, allowing connections to succeed under certain network conditions.
There might be rules in your firewall or NSG that are blocking standard curl requests but allowing verbose requests due to differences in packet inspection or logging mechanisms.

Second question is: if I wanto to prevent access to internet in this setup should I only add Egress with special config.
Thanks in advance!

I guess since in verbose mode it includes more detailed steps in the DNS resolution, so it might inadvertently bypass some DNS-related issues.

does it mean that I can consider responce 200 on http req with -v? I f I do curl -vI
https://www.google.com or curl --tlsv1.2 -v https://www.google.com I see 200...

yes, you can consider it

Yes, your research is correct.  curl  shows different outcomes with and without the  -v  flag is that verbose mode provides more information about the connection process, that might not be visible in non-verbose mode. This can include DNS resolution issues, differences in packet inspection or logging mechanisms, and other network conditions that might affect the connection. But still, you can manually test it out using tcpdump to compare the traffic generated by both curl commands to see if there are significant differences in packet structure, timing, or content.
what you can do is deploy one more pod in your setup that has tcpdump installed.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: tcpdump-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: tcpdump
    image: nicolaka/netshoot
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep infinity"]
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add: ["NET_ADMIN", "NET_RAW"]



Then exec into the pod kubectl exec -it tcpdump-pod -- /bin/sh
Run tcpdump to capture traffic
tcpdump -i any -w /tmp/curl_output.pcap

and do in a new window
curl www.google.com
curl -v www.google.com

Later download the curl_output.pcap file and verify kubectl cp default/tcpdump-pod:/tmp/curl_output.pcap ./curl_output.pcap

Coming to your second question, if you want to prevent access to the internet in your setup, why not consider to setup a private aks cluster

or as you suggested can add an Egress with special configuration to block outbound traffic to the internet.
How?
while setting up your aks cluster choose network policy plugin such as Calico.
Define a network policy that restricts egress traffic to the internet
This one is to deny all egress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-all-egress
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress: []

and if you want to allow egress traffic only to certain internal IP addresses and deny rest then add those specific ip address as below
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-internal-egress
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.0.0.0/16
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 192.168.0.0/16
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 172.16.0.0/12


References:

Troubleshoot connection issues to pods or services within an AKS cluster (internal traffic)
Basic troubleshooting of outbound connections from an AKS cluster

